# AppJS - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL

Tags: jquery, html, appjs

I'm making a desktop app where i can filter some specificed div inside of iframe with AppJS. I'm having a problem i couldn't hide some divs, there is a code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>

</style>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script>
function resizeIframe(newHeight)
{
    document.getElementById('iframe1').style.height = parseInt(newHeight,10) + 10 + 'px';
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>



</head>
<body onload='parent.resizeIframe(document.body.scrollHeight)'>
<h1>hello world</h1>
<iframe name='iframe1' id="iframe1" src="http://www.example.com" frameborder="0" border="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-style: none;width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>


<script>
$(function(){
            var f=$('#iframe1')
            f.load(function(){ 
                f.contents().find('div').hide(); 
            })



        })

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I got errors from console Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL

Is possible to fix that?

Comment: js cannot accomplish task under normal condition....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it directly because of [Cross-Domain Policy](http://jimbojw.com/wiki/index.php?title=Introduction_to_Cross-Domain_Ajax).

However, you can first get content of the targeted url using php script from your own server (proxy) and then load its content in javascript/jquery. This is just a little fix and is not suitable for all kind of page you wish to load.

For example:

```
<iframe src="path_to_my_server_php_script/iframe.php?url=http://example.com"></iframe>
```

iframe.php basic code: {You could set headers or manipulate html code here too}

```
<?php
    $url = $_GET['url'];
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: Do you have a snippet to get content of the targeted using php script from my server? Thanks!

Comment: this is insane, what is a web browser policy doing in my desktop app

Answer (score 1):

Add an option to the create window call to turn off security:

disableSecurity:true

See wiki page for an example: https://github.com/appjs/appjs/wiki/app-object

This setting should turn off the cross-domain policy.